# PrintTree - No head rule defined for MWE - Bug with version 3.5.2

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

When I'm trying to print the tree of a sentence I've parsed using the RNN parser, it crashes when there is a MWE dependency in the sentence. It crashes with the latest version of the Stanford NLP (3.5.2), but not with the previous one (3.5.1).

Here is the error I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No head rule defined for MWE using class edu.stanford.nlp.trees.SemanticHeadFinder in (MWE (VBG according) (TO to))
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.determineNonTrivialHead(AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.java:242)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.SemanticHeadFinder.determineNonTrivialHead(SemanticHeadFinder.java:437)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.determineHead(AbstractCollinsHeadFinder.java:189)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeGraphNode.percolateHeads(TreeGraphNode.java:315)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeGraphNode.percolateHeads(TreeGraphNode.java:313)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeGraphNode.percolateHeads(TreeGraphNode.java:313)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeGraphNode.percolateHeads(TreeGraphNode.java:313)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeGraphNode.percolateHeads(TreeGraphNode.java:313)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeGraphNode.percolateHeads(TreeGraphNode.java:313)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeGraphNode.percolateHeads(TreeGraphNode.java:313)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeGraphNode.percolateHeads(TreeGraphNode.java:313)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeGraphNode.percolateHeads(TreeGraphNode.java:313)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructure.<init>(GrammaticalStructure.java:183)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.<init>(UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.java:92)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.<init>(UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructure.java:71)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructureFactory.newGrammaticalStructure(UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructureFactory.java:29)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructureFactory.newGrammaticalStructure(UniversalEnglishGrammaticalStructureFactory.java:5)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint.printTreeInternal(TreePrint.java:652)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint.printTree(TreePrint.java:264)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint.printTree(TreePrint.java:226)
```

Is there a way to fix this with the latest version, or is it just a bug that will be fixed in the next version?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is the code I use:

```
String paragrah = "Whatever text that contains MWE dependency.";
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishRNN.ser.gz");
TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("wordsAndTags,typedDependencies", tlp);
DocumentPreprocessor processor = new DocumentPreprocessor(new StringReader(paragraph));
for (List<HasWord> sentence : processor) {
    Tree parse = lp.apply(sentence);
    tp.printTree(parse, pw);
}
```

Comment: The code seems to use the wrong head finder (`SemanticHeadFinder` instead of the new `UniversalSemanticHeadFinder`). Can you post how you called `printTree`? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I just edited my post.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. Make sure that there are no old versions of CoreNLP in your classpath and that you are using both the latest version of CoreNLP and the latest version of the models jar.