# Penn Discourse Tree Bank (PDTB) Parser

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp

I am currently trying to run the following project (https://github.com/ilija139/PDTB-Parser). The text file I used to run the project, is the wsj_2300.txt, which can be found in the "output" directory. Unfortunately without any success. The project is based on the Stanford CoreNLP. What I found out until now:

1. I can't use CoreNLP version 3.5.2 (the latest version) due to the fact, that the project is based on the older dependencies. By using Universal Dependencies, I get the following error message "No head rule defined for MWE using class edu.stanford.nlp.trees.SemanticHeadFinder in (MWE (JJ such) (IN as))". However, the following answer from Stackowerflow ([PrintTree - No head rule defined for MWE - Bug with version 3.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458296/printtree-no-head-rule-defined-for-mwe-bug-with-version-3-5-2)) about the same problem could not solve the problem! If anyone knows how to fix it, please let me know.
2. Nevertheless, due to the fact, that the PDTB parser was last updated 1 year ago, I simply used 2 older versions (3.5.1 and then 3.4.1), expecting that the project run as said by Thematrixme ([PrintTree - No head rule defined for MWE - Bug with version 3.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458296/printtree-no-head-rule-defined-for-mwe-bug-with-version-3-5-2)). Unfortunately, only the first problem was solved and another one appeared. A simple "String index out of range: -1 ()" in the function "buildDependencyTrees" due to the fact, that no "root" could be found in the dependencies.

I tried to fix the problem by simply excluding that the node is build, but then I get an "indexOutOfBoundsException" at the next dependency, because no child could be found... Does anyone know what I need to do or which CoreNLP version/model I need to use to let this program run correctly as mentioned in the Manual?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are using the parser.  But you can get Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 to create the older Stanford Dependencies by setting "parse.originalDependencies" to "true" in the Properties object you use to make a pipeline.  Or if you're running from the command line just include the flag "-parse.originalDependencies"  If you're using the neural net dependency parse you would use the Stanford Dependencies model instead by setting the property "depparse.model" to "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_SD.gz"

If you let me know how specifically you are creating parses I can tell you exactly what setting to use to get the older dependencies.